# Confusion about concept of basis in point set topology.

Tags: general-topology

I'm afraid that I have a big misunderstanding about the notion of basis in general topology. For a given topology $\tau$ of set $X$, if there is a collection $S \subset \tau$ of open subsets of $X$ satisfying

1. For any $x \in X$, there exists $A$ in $S$ such that $x \in A$
2. For any $A,B$ in $S$ and for any $x \in A \cap B$, there exists $C$ in $S$ such that $x \in C \subseteq A \cap B$

Are those two condition not sufficient to say that $S$ is a basis of the initially given topology $\tau$ ? (That is, collection of arbitrary union of elements of $S$ might be not equal to topology $\tau$?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try $S = \{ X\}$.

Answer (score 6):

The conditions you wrote do indeed say that $S$ is a basis for some topology $\tau'$. They also guarantee that $\tau' \subset \tau$. But, they do not guarantee that $\tau = \tau'$; see the counterexample in the comment of @DanielFischer. What you are missing is the axiom which says for any open subset $U \subset X$ and any $x \in U$ there exists $A$ in $S$ such that $x \in A \subset U$.

Comment: ... and this axiom together with $S\subseteq \tau$ will then imply both conditions in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The two conditions you give are sufficient to ensure that $S$ is a basis for *some* topology, but it won't necessarily be the topology you started with.

What the condition $S\subset \tau$ will ensure is that the topology that has $S$ as a basis will be *coarser than* (or equal to) $\tau$, but no more than that.

For example (as Daniel Fischer noted), no matter what $\tau$ is, $S=\{X\}$ will always satisfy the condition -- conversely, if $\tau$ is the discrete topology, $S$ could be a basis for *any* topology on $X$.

Answer (score 3):

First off, here is the formal definition of being a *basis for **a** topology* (notice that I bolded the word "a" -- after you read my answer, if you don't understand why, please comment):

Let $X$ be a set.  Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$.  Then $\mathcal{A}$ forms a *basis for **a** topology* if:

1. For each $x \in X$, there is some $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x \in A$.
2. If $y \in A_{1} \cap A_{2}$ for some $A_{1}, A_{2} \in \mathcal{A}$, then there is some $A_{3} \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $y \in A_{3} \subseteq A_{1} \cap A_{2}$.

Notice that nowhere in the definition above did we say that $X$ is already a topological space with a given topology.  We just said $X$ is a set.  Then $\mathcal{A}$ was just a collection of subsets of $X$.  If $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies the two conditions above, it forms a basis for **a** topology.  Which topology?  It's always the same topology: the collection of all possible unions of elements of $\mathcal{A}$.  You could call this topology $T_{\mathcal{A}}$.

Now, if you are already given a topology $\tau$ on $X$, and you are given a collection $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \tau$, and $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies the two conditions above, it is now a basis for $T_{\mathcal{A}}$, as we discussed above.  Also, since $\tau$ is closed under arbitrary unions, it's obvious $T_{\mathcal{A}} \subseteq \tau$.  But, as Daniel Fischer's comment shows, it's not always true that $\tau \subseteq T_{\mathcal{A}}$.

So, to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a basis for $\tau$, in addition to showing the above two conditions, so that it forms a basis for $T_{\mathcal{A}}$ (the topology that is the set of all possible unions of elements of $\mathcal{A}$), you also need to show $\tau \subseteq T_{\mathcal{A}}$, i.e., that every open set in $\tau$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

There is one lemma that is useful (and you should prove) which can help you prove a collection of subsets of $\tau$ actually forms a basis for $\tau$:

**Lemma.** If $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \tau$ satisfies 1. and 2. above, then $T_{\mathcal{A}} = \tau$ iff for each $U \in \tau$ and $x \in U$, there is some $A_{x} \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x \in A_{x} \subseteq U$.

Once you prove the above lemma, to show $\mathcal{A}$ is a basis for a given topology $\tau$, you need to show 1. and 2. are satisfied (which would give $T_{\mathcal{A}} \subseteq \tau$), and then to show $\tau \subseteq T_{\mathcal{A}}$, you just need to prove if $U \in \tau$ and $x \in U$, there is some $A_{x} \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x \in A_{x} \subseteq U$.

Comment: I wouldn't take this as definition for being a basis but rather as a criterion.
In my opinion, a basis is a family of subsets such that taking its span (all unions) generates a topology. However, not all families of subsets generate a topology. Now one can work out necessary resp. sufficient criteria for families of subsets to be a basis. The usual one given as your definition of bases is both necessary and sufficient. In that sense it can be taken as definition but I discourage doing so as it hides the idea of bases.

Comment: Span: $\langle\mathcal{B}\rangle:=\{\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal{B}'}B: \mathcal{B}'\subseteq\mathcal{B}\}$

Comment: @Freeze_S So you disagree with my post as a matter of opinion rather than false information, but downvote me anyway? Also, I distinctly remember asking a question several months ago about my confusion of what it means to be a basis for a topology, and I remember our interactions very clearly, where the points you brought up had made me more confused than when I started.  I crafted this answer in a way that I felt would best help the OP.

Comment: Votes are personal and private opinion of wether a post is helpful or not.

Comment: @Freeze_S Not really.  Votes are public and meant to signal to other readers the quality of an answer.  If you disagree with someone based on an opinion, that doesn't mean their content is somehow less valid or should be ignored by the community, which is what downvoting indicates.

Comment: Hmm, ok let me rethink this.

Comment: But apart from the voting tool what do you think about my argument?

Comment: @Freeze_S I understand your point, but since what I said is equivalent to your definition of span (which you even pointed out), I see no harm in defining a basis as a collection of sets satisfying those properties.  Is it completely consistent with the idea of basis as in, for example, linear algebra, where we talk about the span?  Maybe not, but it leads toward that idea by suggesting if 1. and 2. are satisfied, then the topology consisting of all possible unions is a topology with the collection as a basis.

Comment: Mathematically there's no harm, pedagogically there's a lot!

Comment: @Freeze_S I guess we will just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Yes ^^ I hope you don't take it personally though.